# Maps and graphs not rendered for NDVI-based variable using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi

I’ve written the code below (sorry if this is a lengthy block) to calculate ESPI which is annual mean minus monthly average standard deviation of NDVI. Though the code ran without any problem, maps and graphs weren’t rendered and GEE returned errors like `Error generating chart: Computation timed out.`, and `NDVI SD: Layer error: Description length exceeds maximum.`

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level2');
var aus = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM0_NAME", "Australia"))
var nsw = aus.filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM1_NAME", "New South Wales"))
var year = 2016

// function for add ndvi band to every image in LC08
function addNdvi(image) {
  var ndvi = image
    .normalizedDifference(['nir', 'red'])
    .rename('ndvi')
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT_TOA')
  .filterDate(year + '-01-01', (year + 1) + '-01-01')
  .filterBounds(nsw)
  .select(
    ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11', 'QA_PIXEL'],
    ['aerosol', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'thermal1', 'thermal2', 'QA_PIXEL']
  )
  .map(function (image) {
    return maskC2(
      addNdvi(image)
    )    
  }).select('ndvi')

var annualMean = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
var monthlyAverages = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(1, 12)
  .map(function (month) {
    month = ee.Number(month)
    return collection
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month.add(1), 'month'))
      .mean()
  })
)

var stdDev = monthlyAverages.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev())
var espi_img = annualMean.subtract(stdDev)

Map.setCenter (149.581, -32.636, 5)
Map.addLayer(annualMean, {min: -1, max: 1, palette: '#112040, #1C67A0, #6DB6B3, #FFFCCC, #ABAC21, #177228, #172313'}, 'NDVI mean', false)
Map.addLayer(stdDev, {min: 0, max: 0.5, palette: '#042333, #2c3395, #744992, #b15f82, #eb7958, #fbb43d, #e8fa5b'}, 'NDVI SD', false)
Map.addLayer(espi_img, {min: -1, max: 1, palette: '#112040, #1C67A0, #6DB6B3, #FFFCCC, #ABAC21, #177228, #172313'}, 'NDVI mean − NDVI SD', false)

var espi = espi_img.reduceRegions({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
  collection: nsw,
  scale: 1000});

var List = espi.toList(50)
var espi_list = espi.reduceColumns({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.toList(), 
  selectors: ['mean'], 
  });

var areachart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(List,'ADM1_EN', 'mean')
   .setChartType('AreaChart')
   .setOptions ({
     hAxis:{title: 'Provinces'},
     vAxis:{title: 'ESPI'}
   })
print (areachart)

var ColumnChart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(List,'ADM1_EN', 'mean')
   .setChartType('ColumnChart')
   .setOptions ({
     hAxis:{title: 'Provinces'},
     vAxis:{title: 'ESPI'}
   })  
print (ColumnChart)

var LineChart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(List,'ADM1_EN', 'mean')
   .setChartType('LineChart')
   .setOptions ({
     hAxis:{title: 'Provinces'},
     vAxis:{title: 'ESPI'}
   })  
print (LineChart)

/* Function for Masking Collection 2 */
function BitExtraction(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
function maskC2(image) {
  var QA = image.select(['QA_PIXEL'])
  var bit0 = BitExtraction(QA,0)
  var bit1 = BitExtraction(QA,1)
  var bit2 = BitExtraction(QA,2)
  var bit3 = BitExtraction(QA,3)
  var bit4 = BitExtraction(QA,4)
  var bit5 = BitExtraction(QA,5)
  var bit6 = BitExtraction(QA,6)
  var bit7 = BitExtraction(QA,7)
  var bit89 = BitExtraction(QA,8,9)
  var bit1011 = BitExtraction(QA,10,11)
  var bit1213 = BitExtraction(QA,12,13)
  var bit1415 = BitExtraction(QA,14,15)
  
  var clean = ee.Image(1)
  .and(bit0.eq(0)) //Returns 1 if the first value is equal to the second
  .and(bit1.eq(0))
  .and(bit2.eq(0))
  .and(bit3.eq(0))
  .and(bit4.eq(0))
  .and(bit5.eq(0))
  .and(bit6.eq(1))
  //.and(bit7.eq(0))
  .and(bit89.lte(1))
  .and(bit1011.lte(1))
  .and(bit1213.lte(1))
  .and(bit1415.lte(1))
  
  return image.updateMask(clean)
}

function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
function mask(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL')
  
  var designatedFill = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0)
  var terrainOcclusion = bitwiseExtract(qa, 1)
  var radiometricSaturation = bitwiseExtract(qa, 2, 3)
  var cloud = bitwiseExtract(qa, 4)
  var cloudConfidence = bitwiseExtract(qa, 5, 6)
  var cloudShadowConfidence = bitwiseExtract(qa, 7, 8)
  var snowConfidence = bitwiseExtract(qa, 9, 10)
  var cirrusConfidence = bitwiseExtract(qa, 11, 12)
  
  var clean = ee.Image(1)
    .and(designatedFill.eq(0))
    .and(terrainOcclusion.eq(0))
    .and(radiometricSaturation.eq(0))
    .and(cloud.eq(0))
    .and(cloudConfidence.lte(1))
    .and(cloudShadowConfidence.lte(1))
    .and(snowConfidence.lte(1))
    .and(cirrusConfidence.lte(1))
    
  return image.updateMask(clean)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of questionable things in your script (including using T1_RT_TOA for a calculation being done over 2016), but that aside, your main problem is just that the the amount of calculation doesn't fit in a single interactive timeout.  There's several things that would speed it up (see below), but the "big" answer is that you can just run the last expensive part (the reduceRegions) as a task to get more time if you can't optimize it to be fast enough.

Other things you're doing that you shouldn't:

1. You're using the [entire feature collection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#dont_use_a_complex_collection_as_the_region_for_a_reducer) in the filterBounds call; that collection has ~220,000 points in it, which all get reprojected and used for testing during the filtering.  You can avoid all that time and cost by just using the bounds of the collection instead.
2. Everything you're doing after the reduceRegions call looks suspect. chart.byFeature is expecting a featureCollection, you're passing it a list.  That's just not going to work.